# Populating Django Model Field

Tags: django

I am new to django , I created a model as below. I want these api_key and secret_key to be automatically populated when new Apiuser is created from admin panel.

logic for generating api_key and secret_key

```
".join([random.choice(string.letters + string.digits + string.punctuation) for _ in xrange(64)])
```

Here is model:

```
class ApiUser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    api_key = RandomAlphaNum(editable=False)
    secret_key = RandomAlphaNum(editable=False)
    quota = models.IntegerField()
    used = models.IntegerField()
    datejoined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

Comment: I'd suggest go with sha1. It's fast and random enough for most purpose. Otherwise, try os.urandom that's crypt-random, not psudeo-random. I can understand your intend using the original code - mod 64, but I don't see security point using that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `post_save` signal, e.g.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import MyModel

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    # do stuff
```

More on signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/